# Google Calendar API Flutter invalid_request

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a function to add events to the google calendar. I did it using the following document: [Flutter: Use Google Calendar API — Adding the events to Calendar](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-use-google-calendar-api-adding-the-events-to-calendar-3d8fcb008493). My codes are like this:

```
    return Event(
        summary: "summary",
        start: EventDateTime(dateTime: startTime, timeZone: "GMT+03:00"),
        end: EventDateTime(
        dateTime: endTime,
        timeZone: "GMT+03:00")); // Create object of event
  }
```

```
    try {
      clientViaUserConsent(credentials, _scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient client){
        var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
        String calendarId = "primary";
        calendar.events.insert(event,calendarId).then((value) {
          print("ADDEDDD_________________${value.status}");
          if (value.status == "confirmed") {
            print('Event added in google calendar');
          } else {
            print("Unable to add event in google calendar");
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating event $e');
    }
  }
```

```
void prompt(String url) async {

    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

[Access denied: The request sent by  is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IBas.png)

I think that the problem stem from [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/loopback-migration?hl=tr). But I could not understand how to fix it.

Comment: I assumed you have implemented a sign in method right?